# How to create a java.io.File from a ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, file-io

I'm reading a bunch of files from an FTP. Then I need to unzip those files and write them to a fileshare.

I don't want to write the files first and then read them back and unzip them. I want to do it all in one go. Is that possible?

This is my code

```
FTPClient fileclient = new FTPClient();
..

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
fileclient.retrieveFile(filename, out);

??????? //How do I get my out-stream into a File-object? 

File file = new File(?);

ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file,ZipFile.OPEN_READ);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create the `File` object.

If you want to save the file you should pipe the stream directly into a `ZipOutputStream`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(out);

// do whatever with your zip file
```

If, instead, you want to open the just retrieved file work with the `ZipInputStream`:

```
new ZipInputStream(fileClient.retrieveFileStream(String remote));
```

Just read the doc [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html)

Answer (score 4):

You should use a `ZipInputStream` wrapped around the `InputStream` returned from `FTPClient`'s `retrieveFileStream(String remote)`.

Comment: Excellent answer. I think Jack was the first to answer and his answer had some code in it which helped me.

Comment: Hover your mouse over "answered 1 hour ago" and the tooltip shows you the post time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream( out.toByteArray() ) );
```

Then read your data from the ZipInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just create a `FileOutputStream` and then write the data from that:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
try {
  out.writeTo(fos);
} finally {
  fos.close();
}
```

Then just create the `File` object:

```
File file = new File(filename);
```

You need to understand that a `File` object doesn't represent any real data on disk - it's just a filename, effectively. The file doesn't even have to exist. If you want to actually *write data*, that's what `FileOutputStream` is for.

EDIT: I've just spotted that you didn't want to write the data out first - but that's what you've *got* to do, if you're going to pass the file to something that expects a genuine file with data in.

If you don't want to do that, you'll have to use a different API which *doesn't* expect a file to exist... as per Qwerky's answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, for what you are trying to do, you don't need to write the downloaded ZIP "file" to the file system at all.

Having said that, I'd like to point out a misconception in your question, that is also reflected in some of the answers.

In Java, a `File` object does no really represent a file at all.  Rather, it represents a file *name* or *path".  While this name or path often corresponds to an actual file, this doesn't need to be the case.

This may sound a bit like hair-splitting, but consider this scenario:

```
File dir = new File("/tmp/foo");
boolean isDirectory = dir.isDirectory();
if (isDirectory) {
    // spend a long time computing some result
    ...
    // create an output file in 'dir' containing the result
}
```

Now if instances of the `File` class represented objects in the file system, then you'd expect the code that creates the output file to succeed (modulo permissions).  But in fact, the create could fail because, something deleted the "/tmp/foo", or replaced it with a regular file.

It must be said that *some* of the methods on the `File` class do seem to assume that the `File` object does correspond to a real filesystem entity.  Examples are the methods for getting a file's size or timestamps, or for listing the names in a directory.  However, in each case, the method is specified to throw an exception if the actual file does not exist or has the wrong type for the operation requested.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the ByteArrayOutputStream to a FileOutputStream.